# MS Access passthrough query user messaging

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, msgbox, pass-through

I am using a command button on an MS Access form to allow the user to initiate a job on SQL Server and another button to execute a stored procedure on the server by way of passthrough queries. Is there any way I can notify the user in a MSgBox about the successful completion or failure of the query? Is there any parameters I can use for this?

THank you in advance for your help

Comment: Is the button running a saved macro or VBA?

Comment: Its running a passthorugh query that executes the stored proc

Comment: You could wrap the call in a macro to trap errors. Here's a MSDN guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177418(v=office.12).aspx